# Existence of first passage time density for time-inhomogeneous diffusion

Tags: probability-distributions, stochastic-processes

Let $X$ be a time-inhomogeneous diffusion process in $\mathbb{R}^d$:
$$dX_t=b(t,X_t)dt+\Sigma(t,X_t)dB_t,$$
where $\Sigma_{d\times d}$ is uniformly elliptic, and coefficients are such that the above SDE has a unique strong solution. Let $D\subset \mathbb{R}^d$ be a bounded domain. For $x\in D$, denote the first passage time across $\partial D$ starting from $x$ as $\tau_D^x$.

**My question**: Is the distribution of $\tau_D^x$ absolutely continuous with respect to the Lebesgue measure? Are there any references for this?

Thank you very much.